# Basic use of UIListContentConfiguration and UIBackgroundConfiguration in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios14

I'm trying to experiment with replacing my UITableViewCell configuration with the new iOS 14 UIListContentConfiguration and UIBackgroundConfiguration, but I don't see how to perform even the most elementary customizations.

For example, I've got a test cell where, in my data source `cellForRowAt:`, I was configuring the background like this:

```
let v = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"linen.png"))
v.contentMode = .scaleToFill
cell.backgroundView = v

let v2 = UIView()
v2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
cell.selectedBackgroundView = v2
```

The idea is that we have an image as the background of the cell, and when the user taps on the cell to select it, we overlay that with a transparent blue tint. The `selectedBackgroundView` sits in front of the `backgroundView` when the cell is selected.

Okay, so how do I do that with UIBackgroundConfiguration? I see how to configure the background view:

```
var back = UIBackgroundConfiguration.listPlainCell()
let v = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"linen.png"))
v.contentMode = .scaleToFill
back.customView = v
cell.backgroundConfiguration = back
```

But what about what happens when there's a selection? There's no `selectedCustomView`, and I don't see any provision here for different backgrounds for different states.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following seems to be what you're expected to do. In `cellForRowAt:`, instead of configuring the background view, tell the cell not to update its background automatically:

```
cell.automaticallyUpdatesBackgroundConfiguration = false
```

What that means is: I've got a custom cell subclass, it overrides `updateConfiguration(using:)`, and I want you to call that override whenever you need the background configuration.

Okay, so now do that. In your cell subclass, override `updateConfiguration(using:)`. In that override, do whatever you would have done in `cellForRowAt:`, but now you can take account of the current state. There is no `selectedCustomView`, so just do or don't overlay the selection tint on top of the `customView` itself:

```
class MyCell : UITableViewCell {
    override func updateConfiguration(using state: UICellConfigurationState) {
        var back = UIBackgroundConfiguration.listPlainCell().updated(for: state)
        let v = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"linen.png"))
        v.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        if state.isSelected || state.isHighlighted {
            let v2 = UIView()
            v2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
            v.addSubview(v2)
            v2.frame = v.bounds
            v2.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        }
        back.customView = v
        self.backgroundConfiguration = back
    }
}
```

That works as expected. When the cell is selected, it has the blue tint; when it isn't, it doesn't.

At first blush, it may seem nutty to have to create a cell subclass just for this. But that is, in fact, the whole point. The entire philosophy of this new configuration-based architecture is that it was *never* the business of the data source (`cellForRowAt`) to configure the cell's *view* features in detail. The configuration should be *lightweight* from the point of view of the data source. Let the *cell* worry about what the configuration *means* in terms of its subviews.